# "log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Cannot find Property [evaluator] to set object on [log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender]"

Tags: log4net

Am getting below error from log4net configuration even though the evaluator property available in the configuration file. Could you please help on this?

Error:

log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Cannot find Property [evaluator] to set object on [log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender]

Configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <configuration>   <log4net>
    <appender name="logFileError" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
      <file value="C:\Users\E0433988\Documents\Logs\Wrapper\Error.log"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="100KB"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
      <datePattern value="_yyyy_MM_dd"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="30"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
        <threshold value="ERROR"/>
      </evaluator>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
        <levelToMatch value="ERROR"/>
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %thread %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="logInfo" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
      <file value="C:\Users\E0433988\Documents\Logs\Wrapper\Info.log"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="100KB"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
      <datePattern value="_yyyy_MM_dd"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="30"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
        <threshold value="INFO"/>
      </evaluator>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
        <levelToMatch value="INFO"/>
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %thread %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="logDebug" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
      <file value="C:\Users\E0433988\Documents\Logs\Wrapper\Debug.log"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="100KB"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
      <datePattern value="_yyyy_MM_dd"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="30"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
        <threshold value="DEBUG"/>
      </evaluator>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
        <levelToMatch value="DEBUG"/>
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %thread %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="logWarn" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
        <file value="C:\Users\E0433988\Documents\Logs\Wrapper\Warn.log"/>
        <appendToFile value="true"/>
        <maximumFileSize value="100KB"/>
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="2"/>
        <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
        <datePattern value="_yyyy_MM_dd"/>
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="30"/>
        <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
        <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
            <threshold value="WARN"/>
        </evaluator>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
            <levelToMatch value="WARN"/>
        </filter>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %thread %logger - %message%newline"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="logFileError"/>
      <appender-ref ref="logInfo"/>
      <appender-ref ref="logDebug"/>
      <appender-ref ref="logWarn"/>
    </root>   </log4net> </configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

An `evaluator` can only be configured on an appender that derives from
[`BufferingAppenderSkeleton`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.11/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.BufferingAppenderSkeleton.html):

- `AdoNetAppender`,
- `BufferingForwardingAppender`
- `RemotingAppender`
- `SmtpAppender`
- `SmtpPickupDirAppender`.

Since the [`RollingFileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Appender_RollingFileAppender.htm) does not derive from `BufferingAppenderSkeleton` there is no such property to configure.

To solve, remove it from your configuration.

Comment: If i remove evaluator, will it make any difference in writing logs?

Comment: No, it has no meaning for the `RollingFileAppender` you are using. I noticed you had the `evaluator` and `filter` configured similary; for your case the `filter` will be the most important.